# SQL Server 2008 Using RANK to Dynamically Number Rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, rank

I have a stored procedure that pulls data for a SS Report. I need to include a Row Number column but I have never used RANK before and I'm gettig this error: Column 'WL.SSN' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.. Can anyone help me with the syntax? Here is what I have so far.

```
    SELECT
        WL.SSN,
        WL.LastName,
        WL.FirstName,
        WL.AddressLine1,
        WL.AddressLine2,
        WL.AddressLine3,
        WL.City,
        WL.State,
        WL.ZipCode,
        WL.Plus4,
        S.SeminarID,
        S.SeminarType,
        RANK = Count(*)                     
    FROM 
        @tblWaitList WL
        INNER JOIN @tblSeminar S ON WL.SeminarGuid=S.SeminarGuid
    WHERE
        S.SeminarID = @SeminarID AND S.SeminarType = @SeminarType
        AND RowNumber = COUNT(*)    
    ORDER BY
        RANK
```

I have tried almost every approach to this from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186133 but I'm missing something.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to acheive...

```
 Rank        Au_Lname              Au_Fname
 ----        --------------        -----------
 1         Bennet                Abraham
 2         Blotchet-Halls        Reginald
 3         Carson                Cheryl
 4         DeFrance              Michel
 5         del Castillo          Innes
 6         Dull                  Ann
 7         Greene                Morningstar
 8         Green                 Marjorie
```

Comment: I need to include a Row Number column. In other words I would like to have a column that displays the number of rows in the dataset. I need a dataset that contains a field that will give the rows ordered numbering starting at 1. I've been trying to use RANK to preform this but I havn't been successful.

Comment: No I actually want to order by the rank number. I'm unsure of what tied rank is, I've never used this method before. I think I'm missing a group by clause.

Comment: That may be why im having a problem. I think I should be using a group by clause somewhere.

Comment: The example results come from a query that is correct. Not my query because it wasn't correct. But it does follow the same pattern Raihan's answer below explains what I was tying to do.

Comment: Ok. I appologize for my "completely inability" to explain my problem. I think I did a good job. I explained my query, gave an example of a correct query, and explained in my post that I needed to use rank to find the count of rows for a dataset. It couldn't have been completely unclear. Raihan understood the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY WL.LastName, WL.FirstName) as rank, WL.LastName, WL.FirstName 
FROM  @tblWaitList WL         
INNER JOIN @tblSeminar S 
ON WL.SeminarGuid=S.SeminarGuid     
WHERE S.SeminarID = @SeminarID AND S.SeminarType = @SeminarType         
ORDER BY rank ;
```

Comment: Yes I was missing the OVER clause. Thank you!