# SQL Server, joining on generated rank()

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, rank

I've been searching for a little while now trying to find a way to use rank() as a column to use for a join. I've looked at a few resources, [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx), [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997579/sql-server-2008-using-rank-to-dynamically-number-rows). And none of these match exactly what I want to accomplish.

What I have been given is a string of id's deliminated by a space. I need to assign these ids in no particular order to my Animal table. I am working inside a platform that will only allow me to do this in sql, so using a high level programming language is not an option.

Here is an example.

I want to take my string, "345345 345436 678768" parse it out and fill out my table like so

```
|Name     |ID    |
------------------
|Monkey   |345345| 
|Bird     |345436| 
|Horse    |678768|
```

I have already written a function that takes my string, breaks it apart and numbers it. So when I give my split function "345345 345436 678768" I get:

```
|Num |ID    |
-------------
|1   |345345| 
|2   |345436| 
|3   |678768|
```

So now I want to do something like this:

```
select name, (rank() over( order by name)) as rank_num
from dbo.Split(" ", "345345 345436 678768") split, animal
where num = rank_num
```

But I get "Invalid column name 'rank_num'

Comment: Don't understand. What other information is in the Animal table? Where does `num` come from? What exactly does the rank accomplish (it seems that you want to order something, but what? Your desired output doesn't seem to be ordered by animal name, if that's what column "animal" represents in your rank() function). How do you know which num belongs to which animal? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: You can't reference the alias to rank_num like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM 
(
    select name, (rank() over( order by name)) as rank_num
    from animal
) as a
JOIN dbo.Split(" ", "345345 345436 678768") split ON split.num = a.rank_num
```